# Would a late 2008 MacBook run with 8 GB or RAM if correctly purchased?

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade, memory

We've got a late 2008 MacBook (already upgraded to 4GB RAM), it's fine -speed wise, but when checking the activity monitor were very close to running out of space -RAM wise.

What I would like to do is upgrade the RAM to 8GB, but checking the Crucial website, it looks like the most RAM I can get in is 4GB. Is this correct or is there a way I can upgrade to 8GB? What would be preventing you using 8GB RAM?

[image: ram screen shot]

Answer (score 4):

It is certainly possible to install 8GB of RAM on this model. You will need to check if you have the correct Boot ROM Version and install it if needed. Follow [this guide](http://blog.macsales.com/9102-secret-firmware-lets-late-08-macbooks-use-8gb).

You can learn what RAM to buy for your MacBook using System Profiler.

Answer (score -1):

You can always reclaim the "inactive" memory with the `purge` command. Open a terminal window, type in `purge` and press enter. Most of the "inactive" memory will become free.

Comment: This ought to be a comment; doesn't answer the question.